# Memory address issue Buffer Overflow

Tags: new-operator, buffer-overflow

I'm currently taking a class through sans and in the buffer overflow section i am getting a different  memory address than what the course says i should get. i get "Overflow the buffer to execute the function at memory address: 0x56556207" the course suggests i should be receiving it at memory address 0x56555c7.

Ive checked the code multiple times and have even started from scratch and still get the same output. i am brand new to the field and not sure what is causing it

Comment: Is the executable compiled with ASLR? You can check it with `checksec`. If not maybe the different kernel/os is to blame. Is the buffer in heap or in .bss? Please, be more specific with your question and include some meaningful snippet/gdb output

Comment: Dynamic memory allocations should never be assumed to have the same address across multiple runs. If the course you're using is implying that it should be the same I'd take a different course.